# Symfony subforms change setter function

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

On the database model I have a one-to-many relationship between contact and contactAddress.

I created 2 different forms in the ContactType i added the subform

```
$builder->add(
    'contactAddress',
    new ContactAddressType()
);
```

The contact entity class itself have this, but this entity is in another bundle and I can't change it.

```
private $contactAddresses;

public function addContactAddress(ContactAddress $contactAddresses)
{
    $this->contactAddresses[] = $contactAddresses;

    return $this;
}

public function removeContactAddress($contactAddresses)
{
    $this->contactAddresses->removeElement($contactAddresses);
}

public function getContactAddresses()
{
    return $this->contactAddresses;
}
```

The form is rendered correctly but when I submit the form I get the following error

```
Neither the property "contactAddress" nor one of the methods
"getContactAddress()", "contactAddress()", "isContactAddress()", 
"hasContactAddress()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class
"App\Bundle\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact".
```

when I change the field to `contactAddresses` the following error accured:

```
Neither the property "contactAddresses" nor one of the methods 
"addContactAddress()"/"removeContactAddress()", 
"setContactAddresses()", "contactAddresses()", "__set()" or "__call()" 
exist and have public access in class 
"App\Bundle\ContactBundle\Entity\Contact".
```

how I can use something like `property_path` to say how the property needed to be set, because it seems to use `setContactAddresses` which doesnt exist?

Comment: Have you tried using `contactAddresses` in your form type?  `add*` and `remove*` methods are quite optional ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would be causing the error described in the question but you cannot map a collection property to a single form type. In this case a Contact has many `$contactAddresses`, so `$contactAddresses` is a Collection. This means that to represent `$contactAddresses` in ContactType you need to add a [collection field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html). For example:

```
$builder->add('contactAddresses', 'collection', array(
    'type'   => new ContactAddressType(),
    'options'  => array(
        ...
    ),
));
```

With such a form you can update the existing addresses but to add and remove addresses you will need to add some client side javascript. With a collection field, symfony provides some help with this. There is some information about this in the Symfony documentation for the [Collection field type - Adding and removing items](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items). However, for a collection of entities you probably need to look at the Cookbook entry [How to embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

Comment: need to render the form with {{ form(form) }} (I'm only able to do things in the FormType class). How to output 1 element of the collection. Try to set it to required but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should embed a Collection of forms in your main form.

[Read the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).